# predict_proba for a cross-validated model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, cross-validation

I would like to predict the probability from Logistic Regression model with cross-validation. I know you can get the cross-validation scores, but is it possible to return the values from predict_proba instead of the scores?

```
# imports
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.cross_validation import (StratifiedKFold, cross_val_score,
                                      train_test_split)
from sklearn import datasets

# setup data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# setup model
cv = StratifiedKFold(y, 10)
logreg = LogisticRegression()

# cross-validation scores
scores = cross_val_score(logreg, X, y, cv=cv)

# predict probabilities
Xtrain, Xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(X, y)
logreg.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
proba = logreg.predict_proba(Xtest)
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is now implemented as part of scikit-learn version 0.18.  You can pass a 'method' string parameter to the cross_val_predict method.  Documentation is [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict).

Example:

```
proba = cross_val_predict(logreg, X, y, cv=cv, method='predict_proba')
```

Also note that this is part of the new sklearn.model_selection package so you will need this import:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
```

Answer (score 13):

An easy workaround for this is to create a wrapper class, which for your case would be

```
class proba_logreg(LogisticRegression):
    def predict(self, X):
        return LogisticRegression.predict_proba(self, X)
```

and then pass an instance of it as the classifier object to `cross_val_predict`

```
# cross validation probabilities
probas = cross_val_predict(proba_logreg(), X, y, cv=cv)
```

Comment: FYI: I've just tried this with `RandomForestClassifier` and got this error `ValueError: Can't handle mix of binary and continuous-multioutput`

Comment: @vlsd, it does work - you need to add `[:,1]` for your `predict_proba`, as it returns a probability per class ("0", "1") and you're probably interested in the "1" class

Answer (score 5):

There is a function `cross_val_predict` that gives you the predicted values, but there is no such function for "predict_proba" yet. Maybe we could make that an option.

Comment: Is cross_val_predict in the development version? It would be a nice option.

Comment: Oh, you are right, it is not released yet. That should be fixed within the next say, three weeks.

Comment: @AndreasMueller Did this option ever get added to `cross_val_predict` ?

Comment: @AndreasMueller, see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/5127)

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to implement:

```
def my_cross_val_predict(
            m, X, y, cv=KFold(),
            predict=lambda m, x: m.predict_proba(x),
            combine=np.vstack
            ):

        preds = []

        for train, test in cv.split(X):
            m.fit(X[train, :], y[train])
            pred = predict(m, X[test, :])
            preds.append(pred)

        return combine(preds)
```

This one returns predict_proba.
If you need both predict and predict_proba just change `predict` and `combine` arguments:

```
def stack(arrs):
    if arrs[0].ndim == 1:
        return np.hstack(arrs)
    else:
        return np.vstack(arrs)

def my_cross_val_predict(
        m, X, y, cv=KFold(),
        predict=lambda m, x:[ m.predict(x)
                            , m.predict_proba(x)
                            ],
        combine=lambda preds: list(map(stack, zip(*preds)))
        ):
    preds = []
    for train, test in cv.split(X):
        m.fit(X[train, :], y[train])
        pred = predict(m, X[test, :])
        preds.append(pred)

    return combine(preds)
```