# scikit-learn - train_test_split and ShuffleSplit yielding very different results

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to do run a simple RandomForestClassifier() with a large-ish dataset. I typically first do the cross-validation using `train_test_split`, and then start using `cross_val_score`.

In this case though, I get very different results from these two approaches, and I can't figure out why. My understanding these is that these two snippets should do *exactly the same thing*:

```
cfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50)

scores = cross_val_score(cfc, X, y, 
                         cv = ShuffleSplit(len(X), 1, 0.25), 
                         scoring = 'roc_auc')
print(scores)
>>> [ 0.88482262]
```

and this:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25)

cfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50)
cfc.fit(X_train, y_train)

roc_auc_score(y_test, cfc.predict(X_test))
>>> 0.57733474562203269
```

And yet the scores are widely different. (The scores are very representative, I observed the same behavior across many many runs).

Any ideas why this can be? I am tempted to trust the `cross_val_score` result, but I want to be sure that I am not messing up somewhere..

** Update **

I noticed that when I reverse the order of the arguments to `roc_auc_score`, I get a similar result:

```
roc_auc_score(cfc.predict(X_test), y_test)
```

But the documentation explicitly states that the first element should be the real values, and the second one the target.

Comment: Did you try seeing the cross validators with the same random state? Is your data pre-shuffled or even across classes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's the issue but here are two things you could try:

1. ROC AUC needs prediction probabilities for proper evaluation, not hard scores (i.e. 0 or 1). Therefore change the `cross_val_score` to work with probabilities. You can check the first answer on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28787500/predict-proba-for-a-cross-validated-model) for more details.

   Compare this with `roc_auc_score(y_test, cfc.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1])`
2. As xysmas said, try setting a random_state to both `cross_val_score` and `roc_auc_score`