# sklearn cross validation - obtaining raw predictions

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, lda

I am using scikit learns `cross_val_predict` function to perform cross validation on an LDA regression.

Whilst I am doing a binary prediction, I would like to use this function to obtain "raw" predictions as decimals before they are converted into binary.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, cross_val_predict
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
clf = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, random_state=1)
scores = cross_val_score(clf, final_list, lab_list, cv=cv, scoring='roc_auc')
pred = cross_val_predict(clf, final_list, lab_list, cv=5)
```

currently, pred is a binary list, whereas I would like a decimal output in order to perform further statistical analysis. Is this possible with the function used?

thanks!

Comment: What model do you use for prediction? Provide a name

Comment: I am using Linear Discriminant Analysis for prediction from sklearn.discriminant_analysis. I am using 'roc_auc' for scoring.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more. Preferably with code

Comment: I have added code above :)

Comment: But `scores` in your code it is raw predictions. Isn't it?

Comment: scores is the AUC score for each fold, rather than the actual predicted value.

Comment: I am still not understanding. `pred` will be in same format as the supplied `y` data (`lab_list` in your case). Can you show some samples output what you actually want.

Comment: Also, I dont think using ShuffleSplit with cross_val_predict will work each time. Because ShuffleSplit can and will assign same element to the test data in more than one folds, which is not valid case for `cross_val_predict`.

Comment: The output of a linear discriminant analysis should be a float. This is then thresholded to give a binary value matching Y. in this case [0.4, 0.8, 0.6, 0.2] would give [0, 1, 1, 0]. At least thats how the "mechanics" of it works

Comment: So basically you want the probabilities of each prediction. But then, it will not be a single value. It will be something like [[0.6, 0.4], [0.2, 0.8], [0.4, 0.6], [0.8, 0.2]] for a binary classification. In case, you want the probabilities of positive class (for calculating roc_auc), then it can have the format you have commented. For multiclass, the inner arrays will have even more elements.

Comment: Yes, they are probabilities essentially. I will be using them in statistical validations such as pearson or spearman

Comment: You can use `pred = cross_val_predict(clf, final_list, lab_list, cv=5, method = 'predict_proba')` for that. But that will give you the output like first case of my previous comment. If you want the probabilities of positive class, then you need to  use `pred[:,1]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [predict\_proba for a cross-validated model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28787500/predict-proba-for-a-cross-validated-model)

Comment: Has it solved your problem?

Comment: it helped yes thanks :)